# Rearranging cells in a .tsv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a .tsv file which I have attached along with this post. I have rows(cells) in the format of A1,A2,A3...A12 , B1..B2, .... H1..H12. I need to re-arrange this to a format like A1,B1,C1,D1,...H1 , A2,B2,C2,...H2 ..... A12,B12,C12,...H12.
I need to do this using Python.

I have another .tsv file that allows me to compare it with this file. It is called flipped.tsv . The flipped.tsv file contains the accurate well values corresponding to the cells. In other words, I must map the well values with their accurate cell-lines.

From what I have understood is that the cell line of the meta-data is incorreclty arranged in column-major whereas it has to be arranged in a row-major format like how it is in flipped.tsv file.

For example :
"A2 of flipped_metadata.tsv has the same well values as that of B1 of metadata.tsv."

What is the logic that I can carry out to perform this in Python?

[First .tsv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cs_2U7LFATxT0w-EkXw_NAGE_xrKmF47/view)
[flipped .tsv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ajqFPmBMjNEtGfm9zuDQafmQlc_mp3Xg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import csv

# Read original file
with open("file.tsv", "r") as file:
    rows = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t"))

# Key function for sorting
def key_func(row):
    """ Transform row in sort key, e.g. ['A7', 1, 2] -> (7, 'A') """
    return int(row[0][1:]), row[0][0]

# Write `flipped´ file
with open("file_flipped.tsv", "w") as file:
    csv.writer(file, delimiter="\t").writerows(
        row[:1] + flipped[1:]
        for row, flipped in zip(rows, sorted(rows, key=key_func))
    )
```

The *flipping* is done by sorting the original rows by

- first the integer part of their first row entry `int(row[0][1:])`, and
- then the character part of their first entry `row[0][0]`.

See [tio.run illustration here](https://tio.run/##PZTbTqtHDIWvx0/xixuImqLxnAeJSknI4QH2HUXV1ia0aSFESWi1@/L08w@7uUjiGY@9vLzsw/fzH6/7@P6@ezm8Hs/D0@55u9sf3s7yefDt9LfI8fWf03A7PO9O5ysOro/br4/b49X/ztfj99VkOjxun3cvu/P2eHvx6/liMhF53D4Nf22///b0tv92RaDJjQx8Li4uhi/Hr/vT0@vxZeB82O2Hk2XEeTpsr3@/Hu4vZ/VyOuh0CA/Dz78MV3U6XM4uJ/Z4DHLcnt@Oe16eLfK9f7jXmwdQfBr@QYTwZk6Hp@fd4bB9tDT/7g7mf5qOCbePnwaJb38gnXzCPBwtuNVy/efrbj@mudGH4acf8caMk/f3mbpQko8uxFCjzILTmGN2wbeWZBZd1FxcilllllzSzo2vQWbZaY1NnaaacSw4Jq2uZ3tWOW4BlxIjD5uLvhOm@YbVnWrRRqBivuotZIxOmwYQKDFDbk5zrRUzAK0WEOUavczBW2sPrjWfZQ7cyjkuLQeZE6Rrr5iRt/PkQi@R@NWHLnNipJyjyyEUmRvinPDVkGReXcytu0Y5Mm@uVgyY8CrzTlGxQJPPlt@TsqZk5VP43OC2UqpLJTbM4FIuYSwuykJdLoVaelYvC9C2xIOgsVdZRNdbtXBFFkClD@BX@JYF1CXvAVxzwBOsgZoTTZFFdaXDbe/KTXOpdWMhFZVFdyV34jeNBDGoOSTa12LGBEyzFJX8mLyCY8r0JWe5ow5N5lxCkDsIJga@2ovcGS4qsLsmd9SeNdLAGhOupgSPZCLMY/IophxcL0pU@E2R4mCSl9ZVWOSsdS674dM8dl5B4F0s2eJqIRB4I63nMJWKCanwTKxW6NiSMrtG@gaMKktuE6msdvAv@UMqvgPVytIgV1qvMVLBMlsFEFXooSxNCTXpRwdkWV2FbbTrkePStNusoXS9yNL03xMYQ@zcArnFlmwKGllH7bZi9WbLY5gRfXEQVGU1dj4n1/CWlQk7@49Ry7ICa@rdKDHtriymL0YfkyOrbENh9ahPXlbIsRbGTVvomPzJPQSU3busTG94w4ynPyvrcK@NYhm3lYmCPEiByVyZJoopi25hIQlPdxqXslYbEOM7MXfrsRI19mmHrKESepTRSEnW5qTNj51vss5MOgkjY86ljU7qbBJ@eGkl1QKPPRZMqCwxGWNGyrpbndnMxrStQZtbYGR9zVim0d6A0ru9NbxM0LhtWpeNGqiMGa11G/jwqdO/xAxtxgVj48amk00yjiwt8imyycZAND1wZwr@EFr13FUjxJuCGp3YsBwC6yiyBslh5ILGVgw5bJeNu6p0b3jU9N7IXFhD2ON2JSv7o/4H).

If the effect of the sorting isn't obvious, take a look at the result of the same operation, just without the relabelling of the first column:

```
with open("file_flipped.tsv", "w") as file:
    csv.writer(file, delimiter="\t").writerows(
        sorted(rows, key=key_func)
    )
```

Output:

```
A1  26403   23273
B1  27792   8805
C1  5668    19510
...
F12 100 28583
G12 18707   14889
H12 13544   7447
```

The blocks are build based on the number part first, and within each block the lines run through the sorted characters.

---

This only works as long as the non-number part has *always* exactly one character.

If the non-number part has *always* exactly 2 characters then the return of the key function has to be adjusted to `int(row[0][2:]), row[0][:2]` etc.

If there's more variability allowed, e.g. between 1 and 5 characters, then a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/re.html) approach would be more appropriate:

```
import re

re_key = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)")

def key_func(row):
    """ Transform row in sort key, e.g. ['Aa7', 10, 20] -> (7, 2, 'Aa') """
    word, number = re_key.match(row[0]).group(1, 2)
    return int(number), len(word), word
```

Here's a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LnnFRl/1).

And, depending on how the words have to be sorted, it might be necessary to include the length of the word into the sort key: Python sorts `['B', 'AA', 'A']` *naturally* into `['A', 'AA', 'B']` and not `['A', 'B', 'AA']`. The addition of the length, like in the function, does achieve that.

Comment: Hi Timus! Nice explanation.Although, I did not quite understand what  the writer.writerows does and what does it mean when you do flipped [1:] ?Could you please explain the logic behind : rows, sorted(rows, key=lambda row: int(row[0][1:])?

Comment: @MrinalSubash [`writer.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) is just writing the new rows to the file. `flipped[1:]` takes all but the first entry of the list. In both of the files you've linked to the first column is the same. So I can't just take the full sorted rows, I have to make sure that the first entry stays the same as in the original.

Comment: @MrinalSubash [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#sorted) is just sorting the `rows` according to the result of the `key` function.

Comment: what does it mean when you pass lambda as key?  Also , what does it mean to pass row as (int(row[0][1:]), row[0][0])? So you have used row[:1] only because you are trying to ignore the first column of the row  column , am I right? If so , why are we doing row[:1] and flipped[1:] and not flipped[:1] instead?Also, is writer.writerows an  in-built function?

Comment: @MrinalSubash _"... what does it mean when you pass lambda as key? ..."_: Did you read the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#sorted) documentation I've linked to in my second comment?

Comment: Yes.But the sorted documentation doesn't explain why lambda should be used

Comment: @MrinalSubash But it tells you that you _could use a function_ (_should_ was never the question): And a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-lambda) is a function. As you can see I've changed the answer yesterday to use a _normal_ function, because my impression was that a lambda function does confuse you. But again: A lambda function is just a function, actually designed for inline use, like in this case.

Comment: I am a beginner in Python. Just started learning it. So , my questions may sound a but trivial but its necessary for me to understand it fully.

Comment: @MrinalSubash I understand, and in general there's nothing wrong with asking, quite the opposite! But it's a bit of a fine line to walk here, since SO isn't actually meant as a place where you _start_ learning by asking. Its purpose is more for asking very specific questions after exhausting all other options (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/14311263)).

Comment: I see. I am sorry if the questions seemed to be really trivial but you have explained it  with great detail when you explained each step if the function and creating a separate function to sort the celline elements to create a better understanding! Could'nt have asked for anything better! Thankyou fvery mouch.   However,another question that popped up was what if the cell line consisted of multiple characters like 'Aa12'.How will I split it into 4 characters? Will I have to do row[0][0] , row[0][1] and then row[0][2:].Should I be passing this command in the key_func() function?

Comment: @MrinalSubash See my edit. It depends. If you _always_ have 2 characters it's easy: `row[0][:2]` and `row[0][2:]`. If the number of characters is more variably (at least 1) then a regex approach would be the easiest way.

Comment: Makes sense! Also , one more thing. Shouldn't it be int(row[0][:1]) and then row[0][2:] considering indexing starts from 0,right?

Comment: @MrinalSubash Indeed, indexing starts at 0. But when you set `string = 'Aa12'`, then `print(string[:2])` will yield `'Aa'`, and `print(string[2:])` will yield `'12'`. (The right end of a slice isn't included.)

Comment: Makes sense! Thankyou very much! One more question : The exact analogy of  row[:1] + flipped[1:] does necessarily do the operation where the indexing of the celline A2 has well values that are equal to the well values of B1 , A3 ( metadata.tsv) to that of C1(flipped_metadata.tsv) .I need to map it in that fashion

Comment: In other words shouldnt the loop have row[13] = flipped[2], row[25]=flipped[3],so on and so forth until row[85] = flipped[9] and then after which row[14] =  flipped[10] ...so this is the idea in rough .

Comment: Also to put it in lame man terms for every increment in the row of the metadata.tsv file , there is an increment of 8 rows in the flipped_metadata.tsv file and for every increment in the row of flipped_metadata.tsv, there is an increment of 12 rows in the metadata.tsv file. How do I generalize this logic?

Comment: @MrinalSubash With input file `metadata.tsv` the output file is exactly like `flipped_metadata.tsv`(I've downloaded both linked files and have tried it here). See the _tio.run_ link that I have edited in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation.I just dont understand the logic behind row[:1] + flipped[1:].What does this exaclty do?

Comment: @MrinalSubash `row == ['A2', 13535, 20884]` -> `row[:1] == ['A2']`, `flipped == ['B1', 27792, 8805]` -> `flipped[1:] == [27792, 8805]`: `row[:1] + flipped[1:] == ['A2', 27792, 8805]`.

Comment: oh okay , the reason why I got  confused was  because I think you made a mistake here `open("file_flipped.tsv", "w") as file :`  I think its "flipped" and not " file" right?

Comment: @MrinalSubash No, that’s not a mistake. Please try the code. Change the parts you deem mistaken, run it, and see what’s happening.

Comment: I am sorry if this sounds trivial but where are we initializing flipped to ['B1', 27792, 8805] .This is where i  have a doubt . And subsequently, how is it taking values from C1, D1, E1 and passing it to A3,A4,A5 respectively. I have tred your code and it works well

Comment: @MrinalSubash That's how the sorting is designed to work (numbers first, then characters)

Comment: Yes, I get that. You mean sorted function, right? But where have you initialized flipped to ['B1', 27792, 8805]?Like how row is initialized to ['A2', 13535, 20884].